# After updating to android studio 3.1.1 unresolved third party imports

Tags: android, android-studio

I updated the **android studio to 3.1.1** and android sdk as follows

```
 androidMinSdkVersion = 16
  androidTargetSdkVersion = 27
  androidCompileSdkVersion = 27
  androidBuildToolsVersion = "27.0.3"
  androidSupportV7LibraryVersion = "27.1.1"
```

I am **able to build  and run apk** on device but editor not able to recognize third party imports and shows red color for imports and for usage
event after invalidating cache issue is not yet solved

Gradle version is as follows with 4.4 distribution
 `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.1'`

dependencies are already changed from from compile to implementation

This issue is **not limited to one library** having same issue to all the third party dependecies such as Volley , circularimageView etc

[image]

**Update**
I am getting this pop up when doing `installdebug` which says gradle 3.1.1
[image]

Comment: Please show your your build.gradle file/ **files**. This library is quite old, gradle version/plugin needs updating for a start.

Comment: @JonGoodwin using latest gradle

Comment: Add the rest of the Gradle please

Comment: Why did you delete your answer?

Comment: once i diid from command line and studio doesn't show any error but again one next build issue remains same

Answer (score -2):

Typically, this error occurs when you have a compilation error elsewhere and your cleaned project can no longer be compiled. I suggest trying a gradle build from the command line, and editing your post to include the log output.

---

As of this post [`3.1.1` Gradle Plugin doesn't exist in the documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin.html#revisions).

The plugin **does not always match** Android Studio versions.

To match the documentation, make your top level `build.gradle` match this

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.0'
    }
}
```

Also, [Gradle version as of this post is 4.6](https://docs.gradle.org/current/release-notes.html)

Comment: This is wrong, gradle plugin 3.1.1 is exist. each new project created with Android Studio 3.1.1 will use gradle plugin 3.1.1. The documentation isn't updated yet.

Comment: So I'm downvoted for the documentation not being updated?

Comment: Not. Because you're 60k+ user and is expected to do research before answering. Your voice has a great influence in SO and people tend to believe you without question. So, you need to give them an answer backed by a research.

Comment: I historically have been wrong. My rep doesn't matter. My research only goes as far as the documentation when I haven't actually made a new Android application  for several years. Besides, OP says they got it to build and install from the terminal.